# Read multiple XML files, cleanup and merge with existing dataframe in R studio

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to read multiple XML files within a single directory, extract data and clean up a column then lookup/merge with an existing data frame.

I've seen other questions on here for both reading multiple files and cleaning up column data yet can't get it to work.

I want to:

1. Extract the same elements from multiple XML files that are (or should be) structured the same way. All files are in the same folder.
2. Clean up the filenumber column as it gives 'ebooks/100' or 'ebooks/5589' and I want it to be just '100' or '5589'
3. With the cleaned up filenumber lookup an existing column in a data frame of 800 ebooks and add the new columns. I'm not sure if I'm better off extracting all the data from 55,000 XML files which is time consuming but only needs running once, or selecting the 800 books in step 1.
4. Apply success/fail criteria on whether the new downloads column is 30 or less =Failure, downloads>30 =Success)

The terms I want to extract from the XML (was Project Gutenberg RDF but converted to XML as seemed easier to work with) are:

- //dcterms:title
- //pgterms:downloads
- //pgterms:ebook/@rdf:about (this is the column that needs cleaning)

So the data frame for the extracted XML should look like the following:

```
xmlframe

Title                        Filenumber   Downloads
Complete works of Shakespeare    100      3369
Robinson Crusoe                  12623    2189
Prisoner of Zenda                95       25
```

I then want to merge it with the original data frame:

```
original_data

Title                        Filenumber    Downloads    Status
Complete works of Shakespeare    100           4790    SUCCESS
Robinson Crusoe                  12623         1978    SUCCESS
Prisoner of Zenda                95            50      SUCCESS
```

To produce:

```
merged

Title                        Filenumber  Downloads  Status  Downloads_2018  Status_2018
Complete works of Shakespeare  100       4790       SUCCESS  3369 
SUCCESS
Robinson Crusoe                12623     1978       SUCCESS  2189 
SUCCESS
Prisoner of Zenda              95        50         SUCCESS  25  FAILURE
```

If I'm trying to do it as an individual XML file based on other answers here but it still doesn't work, when cleaning up the ebook column it just gives 1:

```
library(xml2)
pg <- read_xml("/Users/username/example/100/pg100.xml")

#get title
recs <-  xml_find_all(pg, "//dcterms:title")
vals <- trimws(xml_text(recs))
xmlframe <- data.frame(vals)

#get file number, though this needs cleaning
recs2 <-  xml_find_all(pg, "//pgterms:ebook/@rdf:about")
vals2 <- trimws(xml_text(recs2))
xmlframe$filenumber <- data.frame(vals2)

#get total downloads
recs3 <-  xml_find_all(pg, "//pgterms:downloads")
vals3 <- trimws(xml_text(recs3))
xmlframe$downloads <- data.frame(vals3)
xmlframe <- data.frame(xmlframe)


head(xmlframe)
                                  vals vals2      vals3
1 The Complete Works of William Shakespeare  3356 ebooks/100
```

EDIT to the example XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <rdf:RDF xml:base="http://www.gutenberg.org/"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/"
  xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:pgterms="http://www.gutenberg.org/2009/pgterms/"
  xmlns:dcam="http://purl.org/dc/dcam/"
>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <cc:license rdf:resource="https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/"/>
        <rdfs:comment>Archives containing the RDF files for *all* our books can be downloaded at
            http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Feeds#The_Complete_Project_Gutenberg_Catalog    </rdfs:comment>
      </cc:Work>
      <pgterms:ebook rdf:about="ebooks/100">
        <dcterms:hasFormat>
          <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100.epub.images">
            <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/100"/>
            <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">2458527    </dcterms:extent>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N010770d4a6d74aa5b55c39eb855d655c">
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/epub+zip    </rdf:value>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-06-14T14:40:58.596508    </dcterms:modified>
          </pgterms:file>
        </dcterms:hasFormat>
        <dcterms:hasFormat>
          <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-h.zip">
            <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/100"/>
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-06-14T11:18:00    </dcterms:modified>
            <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">2279312    </dcterms:extent>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N89bc524c08b54a6594240ccf8818fb58">
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/html; charset=utf-8    </rdf:value>
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Ncf9c66f72ad34bbd847dae7f9508e087">
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/zip    </rdf:value>
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
          </pgterms:file>
        </dcterms:hasFormat>
        <dcterms:rights>Copyrighted. Read the copyright notice inside this book for details.    </dcterms:rights>
        <dcterms:hasFormat>
          <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt">
            <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/100"/>
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-06-14T11:16:50    </dcterms:modified>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nefb81f5f85714c5c964f3589029cb59f">
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/plain; charset=utf-8    </rdf:value>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
            <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">5852404    </dcterms:extent>
          </pgterms:file>
        </dcterms:hasFormat>
        <dcterms:hasFormat>
          <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-h/100-h.htm">
            <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">7033656    </dcterms:extent>
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-06-14T11:17:18    </dcterms:modified>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N615edc4ab2e74da8a6962978ead1dc6a">
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/html; charset=utf-8    </rdf:value>
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
            <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/100"/>
          </pgterms:file>
        </dcterms:hasFormat>
        <dcterms:issued rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">1994-01-01    </dcterms:issued>
        <dcterms:title>The Complete Works of William Shakespeare    </dcterms:title>
        <dcterms:publisher>Project Gutenberg    </dcterms:publisher>
        <dcterms:hasFormat>
          <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100.epub.noimages">
            <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">2458527    </dcterms:extent>
            <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/100"/>
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-06-14T14:41:02.065471    </dcterms:modified>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N0a45571345a449c89c177f40d94e0c15">
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/epub+zip    </rdf:value>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
          </pgterms:file>
        </dcterms:hasFormat>
        <dcterms:hasFormat>
          <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.zip">
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-06-14T11:18:00    </dcterms:modified>
            <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">2166912    </dcterms:extent>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N024b7e4e178442eebbe8e86aa362a6f1">
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/plain; charset=utf-8    </rdf:value>
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
            <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/100"/>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nf9d7bb6beb29471795e9096c3716acfe">
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/zip    </rdf:value>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
          </pgterms:file>
        </dcterms:hasFormat>
        <dcterms:language>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N869dca334d39425c983a629d1a8a3538">
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/RFC4646">en    </rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:language>
        <dcterms:subject>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N0fad3feb8fdb4f58824d041fccd1b083">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH"/>
            <rdf:value>English drama -- Early modern and Elizabethan, 1500-1600    </rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:subject>
        <dcterms:creator>
          <pgterms:agent rdf:about="2009/agents/65">
            <pgterms:webpage rdf:resource="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare"/>
            <pgterms:deathdate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">1616    </pgterms:deathdate>
            <pgterms:alias>Shakspere, William    </pgterms:alias>
            <pgterms:birthdate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">1564    </pgterms:birthdate>
            <pgterms:name>Shakespeare, William    </pgterms:name>
            <pgterms:alias>Shakspeare, William    </pgterms:alias>
          </pgterms:agent>
        </dcterms:creator>
        <dcterms:hasFormat>
          <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100.kindle.noimages">
            <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">10189331    </dcterms:extent>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N3ab0025af98e43c980950490d2aa3c12">
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/x-mobipocket-ebook    </rdf:value>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-06-14T14:41:57.941535    </dcterms:modified>
            <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/100"/>
          </pgterms:file>
        </dcterms:hasFormat>
        <dcterms:hasFormat>
          <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100.kindle.images">
            <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">10189339    </dcterms:extent>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nafdd31a0c146463bb289f2b2d6176a92">
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/x-mobipocket-ebook    </rdf:value>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
            <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/100"/>
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-06-14T14:41:29.544991    </dcterms:modified>
          </pgterms:file>
        </dcterms:hasFormat>
        <dcterms:subject>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nf1c1a4b50f9d45d7821119dc1ef4c503">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCC"/>
            <rdf:value>PR    </rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:subject>
        <pgterms:downloads rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">3356    </pgterms:downloads>
        <dcterms:type>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nff80c94b0b52431a817a58ead14dfc2b">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/DCMIType"/>
            <rdf:value>Text    </rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:type>
        <pgterms:bookshelf>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N2d8aac020c354487bbbbc07d6aec32d1">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="2009/pgterms/Bookshelf"/>
            <rdf:value>Plays    </rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </pgterms:bookshelf>
        <dcterms:license rdf:resource="license"/>
        <dcterms:hasFormat>
          <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100.rdf">
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-07-12T05:00:06.369359    </dcterms:modified>
            <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">10868    </dcterms:extent>
            <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/100"/>
            <dcterms:format>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Ndf4a9f6482974e3b9b818ce0b34c988d">
                <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/rdf+xml    </rdf:value>
                <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
              </rdf:Description>
            </dcterms:format>
          </pgterms:file>
        </dcterms:hasFormat>
      </pgterms:ebook>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare">
        <dcterms:description>Wikipedia    </dcterms:description>
      </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Does every XML come with one *pgterms:ebook* as you show?

Comment: of the ones I've looked at, yes they have them. However not 'as shown' as I've stripped out most of the data for my example otherwise it'd fill most of the page.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed as namespace prefixes, *pgterms* and *dcterms* are not defined with `xmlns`. You may have cut too much out. Please post at the very least the root tag and omit other items with `...` and close with root tag.

Comment: Sorry about that @Parfait I've now edited the query to paste the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `gsub` to remove the unwanted text and call `data.frame` once after parsing all needed values

```r
pg <- read_xml("/Users/username/example/100/pg100.xml")

#get title
recs <-  xml_find_all(pg, "//dcterms:title")
vals <- trimws(xml_text(recs))

#get file number, though this needs cleaning
recs2 <-  xml_find_all(pg, "//pgterms:ebook/@rdf:about")
vals2 <- gsub("ebooks/", "", trimws(xml_text(recs2)))

#get total downloads
recs3 <-  xml_find_all(pg, "//pgterms:downloads")
vals3 <- trimws(xml_text(recs3))

xmlframe <- data.frame(Title=vals, Filenumber_2018=vals2, Downloads_2018=vals3)

xmlframe
#                                       Title Filenumber_2018 Downloads_2018
# 1 The Complete Works of William Shakespeare             100           3356
```

And to loop across many files wrap above steps in a function call, and then run `lapply` across all XML files.

```r
process_xml <- function(xml_path) {    
    pg <- read_xml(xml_path)

    #get title
    recs <-  xml_find_all(pg, "//dcterms:title")
    vals <- trimws(xml_text(recs))

    #get file number, though this needs cleaning
    recs2 <-  xml_find_all(pg, "//pgterms:ebook/@rdf:about")
    vals2 <- gsub("ebooks/", "", trimws(xml_text(recs2)))

    #get total downloads
    recs3 <-  xml_find_all(pg, "//pgterms:downloads")
    vals3 <- trimws(xml_text(recs3))

    xmlframe <- data.frame(Title=vals, Filenumber_2018=vals2, Downloads_2018=vals3)   
}

# GET XML FILE PATH NAMES (RECURSIVE FOR SUBDIRECTORIES)
xml_files <- list.files(path="/Users/username/example", pattern=".xml", 
                        full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

# LIST OF DATAFRAMES (TRYCATCH IN CASE OF PARSING ERRORS TO RETURN NULL)
df_list <- lapply(xml_files, function(x) 
                  tryCatch(process_xml(x), error=function(e) NULL))

# REMOVE NULL ELEMENTS (I.E., ERRORS ABOVE)
df_list <- Filter(NROW, df_list)

# APPEND ALL DATAFRAMES
master_xml_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)

# MERGE WITH ORIGINAL DATA
final_df <- merge(original_data, master_xml_df, by="Title")
```

Comment: That's great, thanks @Parfait. For anyone who comes here later, I then converted the downloads to numbers with as.numeric then used final_df$status[final_df$Downloads_2018<=30]<-"FAILURE" to get the Failure rate

Comment: I've been trying to do just this so as to process the same set of data (the Project Gutenberg data files).  Thank you so much, @Parfait.  In my case I am wanted to build up a data frame with basic information (title, author, genre, date added, etc) which I can use to identify new texts of interest.

Comment: @BarryHaworth, great to hear and glad to help from a future reader of this post!

Comment: I still have way to go with my program.  I see that some fields are sometimes strings, sometimes lists, while the author field varies as well.  Just need to set aside from time and work through the variations I guess.  File size and format are tricky as well.